# How to convert a unicode string in a dictionary

Tags: python, json

I have a unicode string after applying json.loads() through which I got

```
u"{'1':2, '3':2}"
```

Now how do I convert it in a dictionary like

```
{'1':2, '3':2}
```

I have tried using

> re.sub

but still couldn't find anything.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Where does the string come from?  This looks like you are serializing things the wrong way.

Comment: Why did you mark this with `JSON` tags? You don't have a JSON value there. The source may have been JSON once, the output is not.

Comment: Your data is being encoded incorrectly, the source JSON string should really be something like `'{"1": 2, "3": 2}'`, then `json.loads()` will give you the dictionary you want.  If you can address this at the encoding step that is really the better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

dictionary_object = ast.literal_eval(stringobj)
```

This supports strings, numbers, dictionaries, lists, tuples and sets, but won't execute any other Python code (so there is no executable code risk here).

Demo:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(u"{'1':2, '3':2}")
{'1': 2, '3': 2}
```

However, most likely you should not have encoded the value like that in the first place. It looks as if you did:

```
obj = {'1': 2, '3': 2}
json.encode(str(obj))
```

instead of

```
obj = {'1': 2, '3': 2}
json.encode(obj)
```

The latter produces a proper JSON object, the former a JSON string containing the representation of a Python dictionary.

Comment: Nice and thanks that was great actually I am using it in django as TextField() and than I am rendering it as json.loads() as it is a part of list which contains dictioinaries but anyways that was great help

Comment: @saurabh: Perhaps you should consider adding a [`JSONField`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-json-field) to your model instead.